# Image Distortion -- Camera Calibration Matlab toolbox

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I am using Camera Calibration toolbox in MATLAB to get the intrinsic camera parameters.
[Camera Calibration toolbox](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/)

I got the following distortion matrix

```
Distortion:            kc = [ -0.37602   0.17432   0.00040   0.00101  0.00000 ] ± [ 0.01253   0.03315   0.00149   0.00174  0.00000 ]
```

I'm using these values to calculate the amount of distortion as the following:

```
KK = [fc(1) alpha_c*fc(1) cc(1);0 fc(2) cc(2) ; 0 0 1];

%%% Compute the new KK matrix to fit as much data in the image (in order to
%%% accomodate large distortions:
r2_extreme = (nx^2/(4*fc(1)^2) + ny^2/(4*fc(2)^2));
**dist_amount =(1+kc(1)*r2_extreme + kc(2)*r2_extreme^2);**
```

In my experiment, the amount of distortion is about 0.8511. But I noted in matlab code; they set the **distortion amount to 1**. Any justification  for setting the amount of distortion to 1???

Comment: Which matlab code is setting the distortion to 1? Link?

Comment: Check the following link: [Matlab Camera Calibration Example](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/htmls/example.html)         if you download the toolbox you will find "undistort_image.m" file. In this file, the amount of distortion calculated.  they setting the (dist_amount =1). Any idea!

Comment: After going through undistort_image.m it looks like they are not correcting radial distortion in their implementation, which is surprising, KK_new would be the same as KK if you set dist_amount = 1 which means they are using a linear model for camera projection